# Informatica powercenter installation 8.6.1 error : pmjrepn (A parameter must be a directory.)

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I get this error at the moment of create domain on informatica Powercenter 8.6.1 silent install :

```
===============================================================================
Informatica PowerCenter 8.6.1
-----------------------------

Cannot create domain.

The installer could not create the domain. Correct the error below and select
Retry. You must successfully create the domain to continue the installation.
DEFINE_NODE_STDOUT:
DEFINE_NODE_STDERR:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pmjrepn (A parameter must be a directory.)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:952)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:921)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:452)
        at com.informatica.powercenter.sdkint.repository.ILocaleManager.<clinit>(ILocaleManager.java:38)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:187)
        at
com.informatica.pcsf.infacmd.InfaCmdMainLoop.mainLoop(InfaCmdMainLoop.java:100)
at com.informatica.pcsf.infacmd.InfaSetupMain.main(InfaSetupMain.java:34)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pmjrepn (A parameter
must be a directory.)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:952)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution comes to life with following:

1) Since Oracle database is the one used : Checking Oracle client 32 bits is well configured (right order path sequence) through ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBPATH

2) Installing missed AIX library bos.adt.debug

Informatica installation and domain creation is successful.